# Modify table (year and 13 columns) to 3 columns in R

Tags: r

My table like this

| Year | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 0.1 | 0.5 | 0.8 |
| 2001 | 0.4 | 0.1 | 0.3 |
| 2002 | 0.7 | 0.3 | 0.6 |

How to change become this style in R

| Year | Month | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 1 | 0.5 |
| 2000 | 2 | 0.1 |
| 2000 | 3 | 0.3 |
| 2001 | 1 | 0.1 |
| 2001 | 2 | 0.3 |
| 2001 | 3 | 0.5 |
| 2002 | 1 | 0.1 |
| 2002 | 2 | 0.3 |
| 2002 | 3 | 0.3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. You can use `pivot_longer()` from the `{tidyr}` package.

```
d <- tibble(
  Year = c(2000, 2001, 2002),
  `1` = c(0.1, 0.4, 0.7),
  `2` = c(0.5, 0.1, 0.3),  
  `3` = c(0.8, 0.3, 0.6),  
)

d %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -Year,
    names_to = "Month",
    values_to = "Value"
  )
```

```
# A tibble: 9 × 3
   Year Month Value
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1  2000 1       0.1
2  2000 2       0.5
3  2000 3       0.8
4  2001 1       0.4
5  2001 2       0.1
6  2001 3       0.3
7  2002 1       0.7
8  2002 2       0.3
9  2002 3       0.6
```